# is this ssis data flow transformation correct?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to extract the substring trackingCode to the point of the delimiter ~~.
So for example:

> www.test.com~~34235645463544563554

I wish to return:

> www.test.com

i am using:

`SUBSTRING(trackingCode,1,FINDSTRING(trackingCode,"~~",1) - 1)`

But it is not working and I'm getting an error:

**Error: 0xC0049067 at aw import from file, Derived Column [1562]: An error occurred while evaluating the function.**

any ideas? if I replace the FINDSTRING with a numeric then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is probably not conforming to your expectations.

Trust but verify.

I would avoid a derived column transform for anything but trivial transforms on data which you know (through direct testing) will always conform to expectations.  The formulas are difficult to read in the single-line format in derive column xforms and you get very little control and ability to try different parsing options and few failure/recovery modes.

I would recommend a script task for this one.  You can route rows which don't comply to a different path and use a data viewer to see what's going on with them.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`SUBSTRING([trackingCode],1,(FINDSTRING([trackingCode],"\~~",1) - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure every line has a trailing number? If not, something like this could help:

```
SUBSTRING(trackingCode+"~~",1,FINDSTRING(trackingCode,"~~",1) - 1)
```

Comment: the problem seems the "-1" part of it. I can't find the start of the delimiter and  move back one space.

Comment: maybe some of the data starts with~~

Comment: the delimiter is definitely towards the end of the string

Comment: I would definitely include an if statement that would check for the presence of your delimiter.